# Get current th index in respective tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#categoriesListing").on('click', "tbody tr:not(.startingbalance):not(.totalbalance) > th", function() {
  var currentIndex = $("#categoriesListing tr > th").index(this);
  console.log(currentIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="{ }" class="table table-striped b-t b-b dataAppender " id="categoriesListing">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th> Jan-17 </th>
      <th> Oct-17 </th>
      <th> Nov-17 </th>
      <th> Dec-17 </th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="startingbalance">
      <th>Starting Balance</th>
      <th>$1000</th>
      <th>$1246</th>
      <th>$1624</th>
      <th>$4910</th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="1">
      <th>Projected Deposit</th>
      <th>$246</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$2273</th>
      <th>$11902</th>
      <th> $14421</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="2">
      <th>Projected Cost Amex</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$378</th>
      <th>$558</th>
      <th></th>
      <th> $936</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="3">
      <th>Projected Cost Cash</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$455</th>
      <th></th>
      <th> $455</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="4">
      <th>Projected Overhead</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$1849</th>
      <th> $1849</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalbalance">
      <th>Total Balance</th>
      <th>$1246</th>
      <th>$1624</th>
      <th>$4910</th>
      <th>$18661</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried a couple of ways but none of them worked .My simple logic is that when I click on a **th** I want to get the current index of **tr** that is  (clicked) with respect of its parent **tr** . I have a snippet  made but it did not return the index with respect of **tr** but it return index with respect of **th** , if I modify my selector to `$("#categoriesListing").index(this);`

```
$("#categoriesListing").on('click' , "tbody tr:not(.startingbalance):not(.totalbalance) > th" , function(){
         var currentIndex = $("#categoriesListing tr > th").index(this);
         console.log(currentIndex);
    });
```

Comment: Just `$(this).index()` should work. If not, please edit your question to include the HTML (or at least a sample of it)

Comment: thanks for your interest i have included the html :)

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan please post this as answer . this solved my problem :)

Comment: Glad to help. Added the answer for you

Comment: to much busy .. forget to use td . thanks for pointing that out . and also thanks for great help :) @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're looking for the `index()` of the `th` within the entire `#categoriesListing tr > th` set. Just use `$(this).index()` instead.

It's also worth noting that your HTML is a little odd - `th` is intended to be use as a 'table heading'. You've used them for all cells so it's semantically incorrect. I'd suggest changing the `th` within the `tbody` to `td` instead.

```js
$("#categoriesListing").on('click', "tbody tr:not(.startingbalance):not(.totalbalance) > th", function() {
  var currentIndex = $(this).index();
  console.log(currentIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="{ }" class="table table-striped b-t b-b dataAppender " id="categoriesListing">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th> Jan-17 </th>
      <th> Oct-17 </th>
      <th> Nov-17 </th>
      <th> Dec-17 </th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="startingbalance">
      <th>Starting Balance</th>
      <th>$1000</th>
      <th>$1246</th>
      <th>$1624</th>
      <th>$4910</th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="1">
      <th>Projected Deposit</th>
      <th>$246</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$2273</th>
      <th>$11902</th>
      <th> $14421</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="2">
      <th>Projected Cost Amex</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$378</th>
      <th>$558</th>
      <th></th>
      <th> $936</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="3">
      <th>Projected Cost Cash</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$455</th>
      <th></th>
      <th> $455</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-catid="4">
      <th>Projected Overhead</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>$1849</th>
      <th> $1849</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalbalance">
      <th>Total Balance</th>
      <th>$1246</th>
      <th>$1624</th>
      <th>$4910</th>
      <th>$18661</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```